# Maintain a Textinput's focus, while pressing a TouchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, focus, textinput, touchableopacity

I have been recently attempting to make my own chat input box for a chat that I've made in react native, but the issue is that when I click on the TouchableOpacity, the keyboard goes down and the TextInput loses its focus, but I want it to maintain this focus, as I am pressing the TouchableOpacity. I have looked into `react-native-gifted-chat`, to see how they implemented it, and I tried using the accessibility prop (like they did), for the View that contains the TextInput and TouchableOpacity, but it still didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../../config/colors';
import { screenHeight, screenWidth } from '../../../config/dimensions';

export default class ChatInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={[
          localStyles.commentingContainer,
          {
            paddingBottom: screenHeight / 70,
            width: this.props.width
          },
        ]}
        accessible
      >
        <TextInput
          ref={ref => (this.commentInputRef = ref)}
          onTouchEnd={() => this.props.textInputOnTouchEnd()}
          value={this.props.value}
          onChangeText={text => this.props.onChangeText(text)}
          multiline
          onBlur={() => this.props.onTextInputBlur()}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          onContentSizeChange={event =>
            this.props.textInputOnContentSizeChange(event)
          }
          style={localStyles.commentingTextInput}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          ref={ref => (this.sendBtnRef = ref)}
          disabled={this.props.value === ''}
          onPress={async () => await this.props.sendOnPress()}
          style={[localStyles.sendBtn, { opacity: this.props.value === '' ? 0.3 : 1.0 }]}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.primaryDark }}>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
const localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  sendBtn: {
    paddingVertical: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    borderWidth: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: colors.primaryLight,
    borderColor: colors.primaryLight,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  commentingContainer: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f9'
  },
  commentingTextInput: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: '70%',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginLeft: screenWidth / 15,
    borderColor: colors.primaryDark,
    width: screenWidth / 1.75
  },
});
```

Comment: Keyboard will not automatically hide itself unless it is forced to do so. Also the accessibility prop has nothing to do with persisting keyboard. You parent component which is calling this ChatInput is causing it to close the keyboard. This code isn't sufficient to resolve your issue, all I can help is explain you that if you simply create textinput and touchable button, keyboard would not close whenever you click button. Check your code and your parent component code.

Comment: @AkshayRao, The parent component containing this ChatInput is a SideMenu from react-native-side-menu, but I do know that keyBoardShouldPersistTaps would help me out if the parent was a ListView, although this isn't the case here.